# Using LocalDB (2014) with VB6 or VS 2005

Tags: sql-server, vb6, visual-studio-2005, localdb

I know VB6 and VS 2005 are old, but for various reasons, for this project, I'm stuck with them. So, if I need to move to something other than LocalDB for an embedded database application, please feel free to tell me so.

I'm an experienced programmer, but I've always developed applications in known client workstation environments. I know what database is installed (SQL Server Express for instance), and what those instances are called. This project is different in that I have a small application with an embedded database. No multiuser access, no security, just a user with access to their own data. Database is mostly text (nvarchar mostly, some ints) and will be a lot of rows (400,000 to Million) but small records. No stored procedures.

I need to be able to deploy this to client workstations. I need to be able to create my database from the application, and attach to it (just on initial startup). It all happens on the client machine. I was looking at possibly using SQL Express or SQL Server CE when I came across LocalDB, but I've read some places that I might have trouble accessing from VB6 or VS2005. If that is the case, then I need to know if I should move to CE or even something like a Access MDB.

The main concern is an easy install for the user.

Thanks for your help!

Michael Mac

Comment: The question was if he's going to have problems connecting to LocalDB from VB6, what's to provoke opinion-based answers in it? And, according to this guy, it works: http://piecesoeight.blogspot.com/2012/04/using-vb6vbscript-to-connect-to-sql.html. I suggest a POC anyway.

Comment: I don't know how else to word it. It either can or can't work. If it can't, then I was looking for alternatives. I'm not sure how that would evoke opinion based responses. I was just expecting someone to say "No it won't, but CE will" or "Yes, it will work". Thanks dean for the link!

Comment: We use LocalDb as our production database in a hybrid VB6/VB.Net application. The latter uses Entity Framework to create and update the database. All database related code is .Net based though. VB6 just calls functions in a Com visible Net dll, that return materialized objects from databasequeries.

Comment: I do not understand the hold on this question: is has a purely technical nature.